# Wordpress: How to redirect feed URL to another one?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, rss, feed

I have a blog built with Wordpress, where I host a podcast. iTunes is currently reading the RSS from  URL "A" (http://ramonkayo.com/categoria/hashcast/feed), but I want it to read from URL "B" (http://ramonkayo.com/feed/podcast).

How can I permanently redirect from A to B in Wordpress?

OBS: I use the Powerpress plugin to generate the feed.

Comment: Blubrry, makers of Powerpress, actually have a help page specifically about doing this: http://create.blubrry.com/manual/syndicating-your-podcast-rss-feeds/changing-your-podcast-rss-feed-address-url/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule as your **very first rule** in WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^categoria/hashcast/feed/?$ /feed/podcast [L,NC,R=301]
```